# MS Outlook - custom Forms & VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have modified the standard Outlook new message form and added a combobox called `cboDepartment`.  How do I access this combobox on the send event? I have tried:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
Item.Subject = Item.cboDepartment + " - " + Item.Subject    
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with `Outlook` forms, but have you tried `Item.cboDepartment.Value` or `Item.cboDepartment.Selection` or `Item.cboDepartment.SelectedItem`? I will play with this and see if I can help with a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

`Item.cboDepartment.Value` should get you what you want (for the value associated with the selection) or `Item.cboDepartment.Text` (for the displayed text associated with the selection).